# Region locale adding from admin panel on edit show value in Admin in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, forms

i am adding a locale for region from admin panel add is working perfectly but i want to show the value in edit how can i achieve this?

here is my code:

```
<?php 

foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $webs) {
                $fieldset->addField(str_replace(' ','_',$webs->getName()), 'note', array(

                'label'     => $webs->getName(),
                'fieldset_html_class' => 'website',
            ));
        foreach ($webs->getGroups() as $groups) {

            $fieldset->addField(str_replace(' ','_',$groups->getName()), 'note', array(

                'label'     => $groups->getName(),
                'fieldset_html_class' => 'store-group',
            ));
            $stores = $groups->getStores();
            foreach ($stores as $store) {

                $fieldset->addField('region_'.Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', $store->getId()), 'text',  array(
                'name'      => 'region_'.Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', $store->getId()),
                'fieldset_html_class' => 'store',
                'label'     => $store->getName(),
                'title'     => $store->getName(),       
            ));
        }}}    
?>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. adding a region for what? Customer? shop? Product? and where do you want to show it? Where did you put the code? Please EDIT your question and add the informations

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt i am creating the region manager extension, and i am facing issue. i have put my code that i have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add the data in **form->addValues**

get the param

```
$region_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');




 if($region_id){
    $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');
    $table = $connectionresource->getTableName('directory/country_region_name');
    $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('regions'=>$table))->where('regions.region_id=?', $region_id);
    $alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
    foreach($alldata as $rows)
    {
    //'region_'.$rows['locale'] for you froms name
    $form->addValues(array('region_'.$rows['locale']=> $rows['name']));
    }

}
```